# Regarding installation of HtmlUnit Driver

Tags: installation, driver, htmlunit

i am trying to installing selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar actually for that i have to set all jar files into the classpath of a java project. But i don't know that where all the jars under this folder "selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar" ? and how to install selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar?  Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question correctly. If you are looking for the jars,you can download from the following sites.Try to used the new jars,as these come with lot of fixes.
Just add to classpath & ready to go.

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Archive Releases:- http://release.seleniumhq.org/